# Issue with Jcrop and IE and dynamically added image

Tags: jquery, image, internet-explorer, jquery-events, jcrop

I'm adding an image to the page and then using JCrop on it, but it doesn't seem to work in IE8 unless I wait a bit between `$img.show()` and the invocation of the JCrop method.  Here is a minimal example where JCrop works also in IE8, but I would like to get rid of lines 16 and 18 or at least understand what needs to happen within those 250 milliseconds.

```
 10       var $img = $('<img id="example" style="display:none;">');
 11 
 12       $("body").append($img);
 13 
 14       $img.on("load", function () {
 15           $img.show();
 16           setTimeout(function () {
 17               $("#example").Jcrop();
 18           }, 250);
 19       });
 20 
 21       $img.attr("src", "/assets/example.png");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with the [script element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh180173), IE8 and under fire legacy [readyStateChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa743099) events rather than standard `load` events for image `src` updates, so the timer is masking the fact that the event is not recognized. The solution is to fork the code before the callback:

```
function imageSwap()
  {
  var $img = $('<img id="example" style="display:none;">');

  $("body").append($img);

  $img.attr("src", "/assets/example.png");

  if(!!document.addEventListener)
    {
    $img.on("load", loadTest)
    }

  else
    {
    $img.get(0).attachEvent("onreadystatechange", loadTest);
    } 

  function loadTest(event)
    {
    $img.show();
    $("#example").Jcrop();
    }
  }
```